# How to name child elements of a parent element by value? SQL server

Tags: sql, binary-tree, hierarchy

Please, tell me an example how to mark all the child nodes to the parent id. Only need to mark those branches whose parent has the value `"need"` (see example image). Using a recursive query, it is not possible to rename all the children of a particular parent...

Initial data:

```
+-----+----------+----------+
| id  | parentid | selector |
+-----+----------+----------+
|  1  |          |          |
|  2  | 1        |          |
|  3  | 1        | need     |
|  4  | 2        |          |
|  5  | 2        | need     |
|  6  | 3        |          |
|  7  | 5        |          |
|  8  | 5        |          |
|  9  | 6        |          |
+-----+----------+----------+
```

Need data:

```
+-----+----------+----------+----------------+
| id  | parentid | selector | parentSelector |
+-----+----------+----------+----------------+
|  1  | null     |          | null           |
|  2  | 1        |          | null           |
|  3  | 1        | need     | 3              |
|  4  | 2        |          | null           |
|  5  | 2        | need     | 5              |
|  6  | 3        |          | 3              |
|  7  | 5        |          | 5              |
|  8  | 5        |          | 5              |
|  9  | 6        |          | 3              |
+-----+----------+----------+----------------+
```

The task is to make the grouping by those elements whose parent has the value `"need"`. I think, I should create a column with a mark, as in the example in the table above, or are there any other options?

I use `SQL Server 2012`

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

I dont't know if it work on Sql server 2012, but i found this [microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765(v=sql.105).aspx), i think is what you want, to make the parentSelector with condition, I use CASE (Transact-SQL).

This is another example: [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18312429/how-to-create-add-a-column-in-sql-select-query-based-on-another-column-values)

Comment: The problem is that with a hierarchical selection, on node 9, we do not know about node 3 and through CASE we can not track this...

Comment: If i understood the problem, you need loop join, like this [stackoverflow join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29795400/loop-join-in-sql-server-2008).

This can permit what you want, but this can make slow the server if the table is bigger than that.

Comment: I don't think, that is the good solution, because the structure (real tree) more bigger, than this example. But thanks for the help, I will get acquainted with this method